# How to separate succesCallback from errorCallback in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have this code:

```
app.factory('clients', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var _getClient = function (clientId, callback) {
        callback = callback || function () {};
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/simple_crm/web/api.php/client/'+clientId
        }).then(function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }, function (error) {
            callback(error);
        });
    };
    return {
        getClient: _getClient
    };
}]);
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('ClientDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'clients', '$routeParams', function ($scope, clients, $routeParams) {
    $scope.user = {};

    clients.getClient($routeParams.clientId,
            function (data) {
                //The block executes clientId is correct
                $scope.user = data;
                if (404 === data.status) {
                    //The block executes when Id does not exist and status page is 404
                }
            }
    );
}]);
```

This code works properly - hides/shows div blocks on the page, but is it possible to isolate the block of code error for example:

```
clients.getClient($routeParams.clientId,
    function (data) {
        //clientId is correct
        $scope.user = data;
    },
    function (data) {
        if (404 === data.status) {
            //clientId does not exist
        }
    }
);
```

Is there anything that is possible and what are the best practices?

Comment: you can use interceptors, for more general http error codes. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code works properly - hides/shows div blocks on the page, but is
>   it possible to isolate the block of code error for example:

You can define another callback for the error and call it when error

```
var _getClient = function (clientId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  if (success) {
    successCallback();
  }
  if (error) {
    errorCallback()
  }
}
```

> Is there anything that is possible and what are the best practices

The best and simplest way is to return this $http promise in your factory so you will able to use all $http promise method in your controller (.`then()` or `.success()` or .`error()`) . You will use one promise only and it can be chained with another promise if needed, not broken by the callback.

factory:

```
var _getClient = function (clientId) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/simple_crm/web/api.php/client/'+clientId
    });
};
```

controller:

```
clients.getClient($routeParams.clientId).then(
  function(data) {
    //success
  },
  function(error) {
    //error
  }
);
```